# Last value from previous quarter, given that it's date is less than or equal the current rows date - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have the following table data:

[image]

I generated the last two columns with the following:

```
SELECT PublishDate, QuarterEndDate, Value, FiscalYear, FiscalQuarter,
FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY FiscalYear ORDER BY FiscalQuarter, PublishDate
                          ROWS 1 PRECEDING) as LAST_VAL,
Value - FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY FiscalYear ORDER BY FiscalQuarter,PublishDate
                          ROWS 1 PRECEDING) as QTR_DIFF
FROM tabledata
```

I am trying to calculate what the differences are between quarters given that the information was published.

Basically, I want to calculate the current row value minus the last value of the previous fiscal quarter (in the same fiscal year) given that its PublishDate is less than or equal to the current rows PublishDate.

If it is the first quarter than the first quarter numbers should be retained without any change.

In the above figure, the highlighted rows show a couple of the problems:

1) The zero value for the first quarter even though it should be the values itself (i.e. 19461)

2) The preceding row is taking the previous row not the previous quarter - its  taking the last value as the preceding row's value - not the last value from the quarter given that the publish date is less than or equal to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: Does @KamranFarzami 's answer solve this? If so you should mark it as accepted. If not I'm up for having a go at figuring this out, but only if there isn't a working solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this yet but looking at your code you are partitioning by the year only, I wonder if this will work:

```
SELECT PublishDate, QuarterEndDate, Value, FiscalYear, FiscalQuarter,
FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY FiscalYear,FiscalQuarter ORDER BY FiscalQuarter, PublishDate
                          ROWS 1 PRECEDING) as LAST_VAL,
Value - FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY FiscalYear,FiscalQuarter ORDER BY FiscalQuarter,PublishDate
                          ROWS 1 PRECEDING) as QTR_DIFF
FROM tabledata
```